# /boot partition is full, cannot upgrade

Tags: boot, updates, disk-usage

According to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) i've tryied the commands below. I've tryied also apt-get -f install but it also doesn't work.
Can someone help me? I'm a kind of newbie at ubuntu/linux.

Thank you

```
:~# uname -r
4.4.0-79-generic
:~# dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]'
linux-headers-4.4.0-62
linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-65
linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-66
linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-70
linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-71
linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-72
linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-75
linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-78
linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-81
linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic
:~# dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-65-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```